# Hiding elements on mobile screen media query

Tags: html, css

i am having a little issue with my mobile side of of things. I am building from mobile up, so my media queries handle the screen sizes as they scale up. I have n issue where I can hide my mobile divs when it scales up but if I want a div in my scaled up media queries it will hide the div if I place it in the mobile to hide there it kills it for the scale up?

html:

```
<div id="menumobile">

<div id="nav-mobile">
       <a href="#"><img src="menu.jpg"/></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>



</div>

</div>


<div id="menularge">Main menu</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menumobile{
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align:center;
}

#mainmenu{
    display: none;
}

#nav-mobile {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 12px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 33px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background: none;  
}

#nav-mobile, #nav-mobile ul, #nav-mobile li {
    position: relative; 
     background: none;  
}
#nav-mobile ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
#nav-mobile ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
    padding: 13px 0 13px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
}

#nav-mobile ul a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#nav-mobile ul a:hover {
    background: none; 
    color: #FFF;     

}
#nav-mobile ul li:hover {
    background-color: #005e48;
        color: #FFF;
}
```

I am aiming at the #menularge id so I want that to be hidden on the mobile screen and show when it scales up. but If I hide it in the mobile css it kills it upward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a media query. Try something like this (replace 600px with whenever you want it to show up):

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px){
    #mainmenu{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

You can learn more about Media Queries here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
They are very useful for responsive design.

Comment: Iv got media queries all in place and working.

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){

#menularge{
 background-color: #FFF;
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

but the issue is that it dosnt allow me to hide it on mobile view otherwise it hides it in my media queries.

Comment: Are your mobile styles before your large screen styles? And are you calling for #menularge in both cases? If it's more specific in your mobile css it may not get overwritten

Comment: Yeah the mobile queries are my main style - everything else is for upscaling.

Comment: Can you show your media query with the #menularge bit?

Comment: You give #menularge a height of 0 in your mobile styles. Try giving it a height in your large screen size.

Comment: I have - there is no joy with it. it is either there or not in both instances.

Comment: It works for me, with display: block, and no set height. http://jsfiddle.net/vs95u/1/

Answer (score -1):

In your scaled up media queries you could add `display: visible`.

```
#mainmenu{
    display: visible;
}
```

Another option and what I have done in the past is move your mobile media query to the end of your CSS or at least after your scaled up media queries.

This is of course assuming your showing the code between your media queries.

Comment: There was no joy with display: visible.

Comment: display: visible isn't even valid

Comment: I apologize...mistakened it for something else

Comment: I always thought display: visible was alright to use, but the element still took up the same amount of space as when it was visible? Maybe that was an old spec though

Comment: I know I've used it before. When I looked it up on W3Schools it said visibility: hidden; it probably changed recently and I didn't catch it.